# Add new columns based on a lookup table in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames:

`df1`:

```
block, name
A, X
B, Y
C, X
```

and `df2`:

```
type, name, area
G1, X, 0.10
G1, Y, 0.20
G2, X, 0.50
G2, Y, 0.75
```

The end result I want to achieve is:

```
block, name, G1_area, G2_area
A, X, 0.1, 0.5
B, Y, 0.2, 0.75
C, X, 0.1, 0.5
```

I am not sure how to go about doing this lookup and adding these two columns in Pandas. I tried different variations of `pd.merge` on `name` without any success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `merge` + `pivot`:

```
out = (df1.merge(df2, on='name')
       .pivot(['block', 'name'], 'type', 'area')
       .add_suffix('_area')
       .reset_index().rename_axis([None], axis=1))
```

Output:

```
  block name  G1_area  G2_area
0     A    X      0.1     0.50
1     B    Y      0.2     0.75
2     C    X      0.1     0.50
```